# "This file contained a virus and was deleted" on an executable I built (and code-signed)

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, winapi, microsoft-edge, antivirus

I have built a Windows executable (with MSVC++) requiring administrator privilege to run (it indexes files) ; I even code-signed it with a code-signing certificate I bought.

It works well on Win7, Win8, but on Windows 10, if I download the file from the browser, then I get this message from IE/Edge:

> This file contained a virus and was deleted

and it's **nearly impossible** for a (non power-user) user to have access to the ZIP, extract it, and run the .exe. (It's very complicated to find the right quarantine place, and remove it from quarantine, etc.; and also it's non-ok for a commercial product)

It's clearly a false positive (I have no virus, and I checked it with many antivirus, and https://www.virustotal.com).

**What solution is there?** (I thought I had tried all I can do by even code-signing it with a certificate from a well-known CA)

Comment: Looks like that specific machine is infected with ZeroAccess rootkit virus. I suggest you to try to download the same file using any other Win10 machine. If it get downloaded successfully than we can say that your problematic machine has virus related issue. You can also try to use other browser on that machine to check whether it allows you to download the file or not. Ref: http://www.malwareremovalguides.info/this-file-contained-a-virus-and-was-deleted-solution/

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT No no, it's not, it's a clean virtual Machine downloaded from Microsoft here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ on which I haven't done anything except download my .exe. (which is also clean). It is clearly a false positive.

Comment: I understand  and I believe that your file is clean. There are some chances that after you install your VM it got infected by the virus. So because of that reason, I want to know that whether you are able to download the same file from other Windows 10 machine or not. It can help to narrow down the issue. if you get the same error on other machines than we can try to make a test with your problematic file to check for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 7):

The file was detected by Windows Defender as a file system indexer. All these files could be considered as a threat. You should [report your file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission/) as safe to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd suggest you to check if you've enabled "Real-Time Protection" and the other settings in the Windows Defender settings. Windows 10 is running almost every file through it before it gets executed (this feature is called SmartScreen and included in RealTime-Protection), so maybe that is what causes it.

If it happens even earlier, whilst downloading, then chances are that this is in your IE/Edge Settings. Unfortunately I am not aware where these settings are exactly (feel free to edit this answer if you know where they are), so I can't help you with that one.

If everything else fails, try switching to a different browser. I'm using Brave myself. It's a modified version of Chrome with a few additional features, but the choice is yours. Just make sure to disable the download protection in the settings as well. A quick browse through your privacy settings should usually allow you to change these settings.